# how tampering of data (already added block's data) in blockchain or worldstate is detected in blockchain and hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am a new learner of blockchain technology. I have a couple of question regarding the tamper proof mechanism of the blockchain.

1) My understanding:  I understood that hash of [ hash the previous block + content of current block ] will go as a hash to the next block. if we tamper content of a block the hash will change and the link to the next block will be broken.

My Question: If a suspect changed the content of a block long after the block got added, will the calculation of hash and placing the hash in the next block happens automatically ?.
Suppose if some one has already illegally changed the content and the link is broken, is there an automatic mechanism to trigger the event that the link has been broken ?.
At what time the tampered copy of blockchain will be identified and invalidated ?

2) My understanding: In Hyperledger fabric I uderstood that ledger = blockchain + worldstate.
The world state is calculated based on the blockchain. The application will depend on worldstate values, the applications will not traverse through blockchain to find a value.

My questions are:
i) how frequetly the worldstate is recalculated ?

ii) will a broken chain(in case of a tamper) is detected while re-calculating the worldstate

iii) what if a suspect tampers the worldstate on a peer. how this situation is set right ? will the tampering be detected during the consensus or any other acticity ?

I read and understood that the blockchain is tamper proof, but really want to understand which processes safe guard the BC ?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a blockchain world where chain has `1000 blocks` and `100 nodes`.

Now `node x` temperas with `block 950` and changes its `hash`. As a result all consecutive block's `hash` changes. So `node x` now has a version of `chain` that is different from other `99 nodes`. As majority of the nodes still has same `chain` it will be decided that `node x` has faulty `chain` and `node x`'s decision will not be taken into account when creating a new block. This is how blockchain becomes tamper proof.

Now lets consider an edge case scenario. Out of 100 nodes 51 nodes temperas with `block 950` and changes its `hash`. Now these `51 nodes` has a faulty `chain` but same `chain`. As a result this `chain` will prevail and actual `chain` will be discarded. This is known as `51% attack`.

Comment: "As a result all consecutive block's hash changes". -- Does this mean any background processes running and monitoring the chain which will change all the remaining hashes automatically ?. If so what are the processes.

Comment: Data of `block n+1` contains the hash of `block n`. So it you change some data on `block n` it's hash will change. As this hash will be used as data in `block n+1` hash of `block n+1` will also change. For the same reason hash of `block n+2` will change and so on.